# How two abstract the number of parameters of a function with type parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, abstract, type-parameter

There is a Wrapper class for arbitrary functions. I tried to abstract the input and output (return value) of the function with the two type parameters [I, O] (for input and output).

```
class Wrapper[I, O](protected val f: I => O {

    protected def doIt(input: I): O = f(input)

}
```

As this should be a wrapper for arbitrary functions, I have a problem with functions that take multiple parameters.

```
val multiplyFunction = (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b
val multiplyWrapper = new Wrapper[(Int, Int), Int](multiplyFunction)
```

The second line does not compile, because the wrapper expects a function which takes a Tuple with two Ints as the only parameter.

**Is there a way to rewrite this, so that I can abstract the function's parameters no matter how many parameters there are?** Ideally the solution would be type safe, by the compiler.

Maybe I there is an alternative to using a tuple to specify the types for the wrapper when creating an instance it.

I hope I don't have to write it like the Tuple classe Tuple2 to TupleN or Function2 to FunctionN. I don't know all the details about this, but that does look more like a workaround and is not a abstract / generic solution.

Comment: You could use `tupled` method on function: `new Wrapper(multiplyFunction.tupled)`

Comment: I did not know tupled. It compiles. :) Need more time to check runtime behavior. Is there a way to make this transparent to the wrapper class's user. I mean that the user can pass an ordinary function and I  call tupled internally?

Comment: See answer. It's too long for comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tupled` method on function: `new Wrapper(multiplyFunction.tupled)`.

If you want to make this transparent to the wrapper class's user you could use duck typing:

```
object Wrapper {
  def apply[I, O](e: { def tupled: I => O }) = new Wrapper(e.tupled)
  def apply[I, O](e: I => O) = new Wrapper(e)
}

scala> Wrapper( (a: Int) => a )
res0: Wrapper[Int,Int] = Wrapper@29d03e78

scala> Wrapper( (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b )
res1: Wrapper[(Int, Int),Int] = Wrapper@581cdfc2
```

You'll get some overhead due to reflection.

Comment: Tricky, but it compiles so far. ^^